gulp concat variables is redeclared
In my index.html, I will call a index.js file
and that file will import other files/variable.
It keeps on say some variables is redeclared after compiling the js files into one file.
As I need to import the same files in other files.
How to solve that?
const gulp = require("gulp");
const { src, series, parallel, dest, watch } = require("gulp");
const concat = require("gulp-concat");
const terser = require("gulp-terser");
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
const jsPath = "js/**/*.js";

async function copyHtml() {
    const imagemin = await import("gulp-imagemin");
    return src('*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
}

async function imgTask() {
    const imagemin = await import("gulp-imagemin");
    return src('assets/*')
        .pipe(imagemin.default()) // Use .default() because import returns an object
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/assets"));
}

function jsTask() {
    return src(jsPath)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat("all.js"))
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(dest("dist/js"));
}

exports.jsTask = jsTask;
exports.imgTask = imgTask;
exports.copyHtml = copyHtml;
exports.default = parallel(copyHtml, imgTask, jsTask);


And are the variables in your source js files redeclared?

no I only delared the variable once, and import them in other files
